# Validate before execute query

Tags: mongoose

I have a "product model" and an endpoint where the user queries the products.
As usual, the user can send fields in the query string to filter the results, but if the user sends a field with an invalid type, for example, a word in a numeric path, the validation fails and throws a CastError as expected.

```js
const ProductModel = require('../models/Product');

app.get("/products", async (req, res, next) => {
    // user sends {upc: "word"} when upc should be a number, therefore validation fails
    const products = await ProducstModel.find(req.qury);
})
```

The problem: Is there a way to validate the query against the model/schema? So that a validation error to be thrown.
Why do I want to do this? When creating a document, if validation fails, a ValidationError is thrown, which has all the errors, so I can respond to the user with it.
On the other hand, CastError is thrown at the first error found.

ValidationError:
`"Product validation failed: upc: Cast to Number failed for value \"word\" at path \"upc\""`

CastError: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "a" at path "width" for model "Product"`

Comment: you can use `joi` as your helper/middleware for schema validation, check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/@hapi/joi

Comment: @KarlL I thought of that, but there's no way to provide joi the model scheme.
In order not to have to hard code the whole scheme and validate it again, I think it would be redundant.
I have all the necessary validation in the model.

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea you can use `schema.path` and check per field in a loop or switch whichever works for you, and match with your `req data` `typeof`s

for example:

```
const mySchema = new Schema({ name: String })
mySchema.path('name').instance //this would result to "String"
```

another option is using `validator` like:

```
var schema = new Schema({
    name: String
})
```

then:

```
schema.path('name').validate(function (v) {
  return typeof v == 'String';
}, 'my error ');
```

Hope this helps somehow.

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but it helps, ty. I think I should be a native in mognoose. I'll try it with a middleware, and then I'll turn it into a plug-in.